# We need limitted functionality like automated installation. Which virtualization is better for us?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012, continuous-integration

We are about to buy a server and we want to make it as our Virtualization environment.

This server will be in isolated environment and will not have direct access to production environment.

We wanted to do autodeployment once the nightly build is over. [Using Powercli to do install our project inside Virtual machine]

We analyzed with ESXi license and it costs around 1300 dollar [as free ESXi is having readonly access for most of powercli commands].

We can't go with VMWare workstation as build machine in production environment and we can't install Workstation in that machine and keep deployment VMs inside.

Whether any other hypervisor will meet our needs? We don't need to have high availability , Fault tolerance and load balancing . We just need to be able to do automated deployment.

I am not sure about Hyper-V. Will it suit our needs with out bite our pocket?

Comment: I find it hard to understand what you want. If you have a tight budget you might consider KVM as well because it is free.

Comment: **We just need to be able to do automated deployment.**
Automated deployment? Could you explain what are you attempting to automatically deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V server is free. That said, you will ned to set up the management. THIs is a larger question - and that it one that can not be answered here. COnsulting time, I would say.